# Axios request GET and after some json modifying make POST

Tags: javascript, axios, request, twilio

I am trying to make a GET request to twilio to get the data from a specific channel after that I need make some changes to it and then post it again.

I am completely new working with js I will appreciate any advice
I am not using Twilio SDK

So far I make this.. but It doesn't make the post request

```
function modifyChannel(sid, json) {
    console.log(json);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let newJson = JSON.parse(json.attributes);
        newJson.task_sid = null;
        json.attributes = JSON.stringify(newJson);
        resolve(json);
    })
}

function postChannel(sid, json) {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url:`https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/${DEV_CREDENTIAL.programmableChatSid}/Channels/${sid}`,
            
            auth: {
                username: DEV_CREDENTIAL.account,
                password: DEV_CREDENTIAL.token
            },

            data: {
                json
            }
        });
}

axios({
    method: 'get',
    url:`https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/${DEV_CREDENTIAL.programmableChatSid}/Channels/${channel_sid}`,
    auth: {
        username: DEV_CREDENTIAL.account,
        password: DEV_CREDENTIAL.token
    }
})
.then(response => {
    return modifyChannel(channel_sid, response.data);
}).then(jsonModified => { postChannel(channel_sid, jsonModified); })
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think the issue is that you are passing `data: { json }` when you make the post request. That's going to expand to: `data: { json: { THE_ACTUAL_DATA }}` where you just want `data: { THE_ACTUAL_DATA }`. So, remove the `json` key from there.

You can also simplify things with your data manipulation. You aren't doing anything asynchronous in your `modifyChannel` function, so there's no need to return a Promise.

Try the following instead:

```js
function modifyChannel(sid, json) {
  let newJson = JSON.parse(json.attributes);
  newJson.task_sid = null;
  json.attributes = JSON.stringify(newJson);
  return json;
}

function postChannel(sid, json) {
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: `https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/${DEV_CREDENTIAL.programmableChatSid}/Channels/${sid}`,
    auth: {
      username: DEV_CREDENTIAL.account,
      password: DEV_CREDENTIAL.token,
    },
    data: json,
  });
}

axios({
  method: "get",
  url: `https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/${DEV_CREDENTIAL.programmableChatSid}/Channels/${channel_sid}`,
  auth: {
    username: DEV_CREDENTIAL.account,
    password: DEV_CREDENTIAL.token,
  },
})
  .then((response) => {
    const jsonModified = modifyChannel(channel_sid, response.data);
    postChannel(channel_sid, jsonModified);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```